# How to use the latest version of flash on Ubuntu?

Tags: flash, browser, websites

We have all read about Adobe's decision to not care about linux users. I have several video websites (things like [tf1.fr](http://tf1.fr) and [m6replay.fr](http://m6replay.fr) that require **an updated version of flash**. I guess this is so for security reasons and for digital rights management.

Since the latest updated version of flash is no longer available for Ubuntu, **how can I use these websites?**

I have tried chromium and Google Chrome, but that does not make a difference. Is there some tool I can use? Or some or other bypass? Is someone working on a structural solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried [Lightspark](https://launchpad.net/lightspark)?

Comment: @Mitch Interesting, it does not look very recent, though. The install instructions are for Ubuntu 10 and 11. Is this still up to date and will it help?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I am running 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution that worked for me was using Google Chrome. Note that this is not the same browser as Chromium.

It can be downloaded from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Answer (score 1):

Do this.  Ensure that universe is included in your software resources and, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-lightspark
```

[image]

Also you can check out [Ubuntu Packages](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/lightspark-common_0.7.2-2_i386.deb.html), to manually install using a .deb file.

Comment: Should I somehow activitate this in the browser? I am using firefox.

Comment: You'll need to restart your browser.

Comment: Note that this is an alternative flash implementation, not the latest official flash version; of course it does achieve what the question asks

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've added an image to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Pepper Flash Player, which is more recent and is the same version of Flash that is used in Chrome (Chromium doesn't bundle Flash). This is available through a PPA for Precise, Quantal, Saucy, and Trusty (although Trusty will have this package in the partner repo, I believe).

See https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash for installation instructions.

Short version of the instructions:

The following adds the PPA and installs the Pepper Flash Player:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

Now, you need to tell Chromium to use this version of the Flash Player. To do that, open up /etc/chromium-browser/default (something like `sudo nano /etc/chromium-browser/default` or `sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default`), and on a new line at the end of the file, add the following line:

```
 /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

Save and close the file, and run Chromium as normal. If you go to about:plugins, you should see it's using Flash 12.x.x.xx.